# Eliminar un elemento de un arraylist bidimensional

Tags: java, arraylist

estoy realizando un ejercicio para practicar con ArrayLists bidimensionales, les dejo el menú en sí:

```
System.out.println("Introduce una opción: ");
        System.out.println("1: Introducir alumno." +'\n'
                + "2: Eliminar alumno por nombre." +'\n'
                + "3: Eliminar alumno por apellido." +'\n'
                + "4: Mostrar todos los alumnos sin ciclo." +'\n'
                + "5: Mostrar todos los alumnos con ciclos." +'\n'
                + "6: Mostrar alumnos de un ciclo concreto." +'\n'
                + "7: Salir del programa.");
```

Y por aquí cómo he declarado todo:

```
ArrayList <ArrayList<String>> listaAlumnos = new ArrayList<>();
    int opcion = 0;
    String nombre=null;
    String apellido=null;
    String ciclo = null;
```

En el caso 1 no he tenido mucho problema, lo resolví así:

```
switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del alumno");
            nombre=sc.next();
            System.out.println("Introduce el apellido del alumno");
            apellido = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Introduce el ciclo del alumno");
            ciclo=sc.next();
            
            ArrayList<String> alumno = new ArrayList<>();
            alumno.add(nombre);
            alumno.add(apellido);
            alumno.add(ciclo);
            
            listaAlumnos.add(alumno);
            
            System.out.println("Alumno registrado correctamente");
            
        
            break;
```

Mi problema viene en el caso 2 y 3, tengo que eliminar por nombre y apellido y no sé muy bien como lograrlo. Estoy intentando recorrer la lista y luego de eso comparar con el nombre a eliminar tal que así:

```
System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del alumno que deseas eliminar");
            String nombreEliminar = sc.next();
            boolean eliminadoNombre = false;
            
            for(int i=0;i<listaAlumnos.size()-1;i++) {
                if(listaAlumnos.get(i).get(0).equalsIgnoreCase(nombreEliminar)) {
                    listaAlumnos.remove(i);
                    eliminadoNombre=true;
                    i--;
                }
            }
            
            if(!eliminadoNombre) {
                System.out.println("No se encontró ningún alumno con ese nombre.");
            }
            
            break;
```

Pero siempre me dice que no se encontró ningún alumno, vaya, que no coincide. No sé si es porque la comparación (con los get) la hago mal.

Si me ayudaran sería de gran ayuda, gracias

Comment: Debes sustituir .equalsIgnoreCase(nombreEliminar) por .equals(nombreEliminar) ya que quieres saber si el nombre recibido por parametros coincide con la posicion del arreglo que estas evaluando durante el ciclo. Ademas de esto, noto que haces i--, con eso regresas a la posicion anterior del arreglo. Para eliminar debes usar pop(i) para sacar el ArrayList. Puedes leer [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452672/java-howto-arraylist-push-pop-shift-and-unshift) que te puede servir.

Comment: Hola!! Gracias por la respuesta, no se supone que equalsIgnoreCase y equals es lo mismo? Sólo que IgnoreCase pasa de mayúsculas y minúsculas... Corrígeme si me equivoco. En cuanto a lo segundo he visto que el pop es básicamente el remove que yo ando utilizando...

Comment: Pues si, tienes razón. Has intentado imprimir tu listaAlumnos durante la ejecución para verificar su comportamiento?

Comment: Sí, los alumnos que registro sí me los hace bien pero al eliminarlos no logro ver lo que falla. Debe ser fallo del get, pero no consigo verlo

Comment: Seria bueno que generes un nuevo alumno e imprimas tu arreglo, cuando haces:  alumno.add(nombre);
            alumno.add(apellido);
            alumno.add(ciclo); estas agregando nombre en la posicion 0, apellido en la posicion 1 y ciclo en la posicion 2. No se supone que todos estos son atributos del objeto alumno?

Comment: Pero primero quiero sacar lo que abordo en la pregunta. Como bien dices nombre se guarda en la posición 0, por lo que no entiendo por qué no me hace caso a la condición dentro del for

Answer (score 0):

Di con la solución, copio y pego mi código entero por si a alguien le puede servir:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    ArrayList <ArrayList<String>> listaAlumnos = new ArrayList<>();

    
    int opcion = 0;
    String nombre=null;
    String apellido=null;
    String ciclo = null;
    
    do {
        
        System.out.println("Introduce una opción: ");
        System.out.println("1: Introducir alumno." +'\n'
                + "2: Eliminar alumno por nombre." +'\n'
                + "3: Eliminar alumno por apellido." +'\n'
                + "4: Mostrar todos los alumnos sin ciclo." +'\n'
                + "5: Mostrar todos los alumnos con ciclos." +'\n'
                + "6: Mostrar alumnos de un ciclo concreto." +'\n'
                + "7: Salir del programa.");
        
        opcion=sc.nextInt();
        
        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del alumno");
            nombre=sc.next();
            System.out.println("Introduce el apellido del alumno");
            apellido = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Introduce el ciclo del alumno");
            ciclo=sc.next();
            
            ArrayList<String> alumno = new ArrayList<>();
            alumno.add(nombre);
            alumno.add(apellido);
            alumno.add(ciclo);
            
            listaAlumnos.add(alumno);
            
            System.out.println("Alumno registrado correctamente");
            
        
            break;
            
        case 2:
            
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del alumno que deseas eliminar");
            String nombreEliminar = sc.next();
            boolean eliminadoNombre = false;
            
            for(int i=0;i<listaAlumnos.size();i++) {
                if(listaAlumnos.get(i).get(0).equalsIgnoreCase(nombreEliminar)) {
                    listaAlumnos.remove(i);
                    eliminadoNombre=true;
                }
            }


            if(!eliminadoNombre) {
                System.out.println("No se encontró ningún alumno con ese nombre.");
            }else {
                System.out.println("El alumno " +nombreEliminar + " se eliminó correctamente");
            }
            
            break;
            
        case 3:
            
            System.out.println("Introduce el apellido del alumno que deseas eliminar");
            String apellidoEliminar=sc.next();
            boolean eliminadoApellido=false;
            
            for(int i=0;i<listaAlumnos.size();i++) {
                if(listaAlumnos.get(i).get(1).equalsIgnoreCase(apellidoEliminar)) {
                    listaAlumnos.remove(i);
                    eliminadoApellido=true;
                }
            }
            
            if(!eliminadoApellido) {
                System.out.println("No se encontró ningún alumno con ese apellido.");
            }
            
            
            break;
            
        case 4:
            
            System.out.println("Lista de alumnos sin ciclo: ");
            for(int i=0;i<listaAlumnos.size();i++) {
                System.out.println(listaAlumnos.get(i).get(0) + " " +listaAlumnos.get(i).get(1));
            }
            
            break;
            
        case 5:
            
            System.out.println("Lista de alumnos con ciclo formativo: ");
            for(int i=0;i<listaAlumnos.size();i++) {
                System.out.println(listaAlumnos.get(i).get(0)+" "+listaAlumnos.get(i).get(1)+" cursa " +listaAlumnos.get(i).get(2));
            }
            
            break;
            
        case 6:
            
            System.out.println("Introduzca el ciclo del que quiere conocer los alumnos");
            String nombreCiclo=sc.next();
            boolean cicloExiste = false;
            
            for(int i=0;i<listaAlumnos.size();i++) {
                
                if(listaAlumnos.get(i).get(2).equalsIgnoreCase(nombreCiclo)) {
                    System.out.println(listaAlumnos.get(i).get(0) + " " +listaAlumnos.get(i).get(1));
                    cicloExiste=true;
                }
            }
            
            if(!cicloExiste) {
                System.out.println("El ciclo de " +nombreCiclo + " no es cursado por naide");
            }
            
            break;
            
        
        }
        
    } while (opcion!=7);
    
    System.out.println(listaAlumnos);
    sc.close();
```

El problema estaba en que al entrar en el if del caso 2 (también aplica para el caso 3) usaba un i--, cosa que se contradecía con la condición del for que era un incremento de i (i++)

Ya con eso el programa funciona perfectamente

Comment: de echo si pruebas tu codigo ingresando 2 alumnos digamos primero ingresas juan y luego lucas si queres eliminar juan lo hara correctamente por que tu ciclo va desde el indice 0 hasta el tamaño de tu lista -1 (2-1) pero si en ves de juan queres eliminar lucas te dira que no lo encuentra por que el ciclo solo se recorre una vez , como te anote en la respuesta tu ciclo debe ser int i=0;i<listaAlumnos.size();i++

Comment: Cierto amigo! Ya lo edité